# Excel: Display empty date cells as "Never"

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with a column named Last Login, and want to display "Never" for all empty cells. I am trying to use conditional formatting for this, and feel like I am SO close to getting it working properly!

I am using the ISBLANK() function as the condition:

[image]

And here is the custom format I am using:

[image: Number formatting screen]
[image: Font formatting screen]
[image: Fill formatting screen]

As you can see here:

[image: Format manager screen]

It shows correctly in the preview window (1), but it does not show correctly in the cells themselves (2). Any ideas of what I am missing here? I am so darn close!

I did try using custom formatting inside Home -> Number -> Number Format, and that did not work either.

Comment: You can only use **Formula** to help you return the Never.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can be accomplished with conditional formatting.

What you probably should do is use the `If` function. You could for instance insert a new column, and set the value to `=IF(ISBLANK(J4); "Never"; J4)`.

Or, if the dates in column J are already based on a formula: `=IF(ISBLANK([YourFormula]); "Never"; [YourFormula])`. The downside is that the formula is now repeated, which may be less readable, and also harder to maintain.

Comment: Depending on the Excel version, you can use something like `=LET(result,[YourFormula],IF(ISBLANK(result),"Never",result))` where `result` is literally the word result. That way, `[YourFormula]` only appears once.

Comment: @EngineerToast Nice, I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

> And here is the custom format I am using

The problem here is that Excel does NOT apply custom formatting for empty cells.

So there is no way to display content in place of blank values.